# Access both state and dispatch in Redux connect callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function that binds both the state and dispatch to a function. E.g.:

```
function bindStateToGetFoo = (state, dispatch) => (arg1, arg2) => {
  const { val1, val1 } = state;
  dispatch(createAction());
  ...
};
```

I'm doing this because I don't want to duplicate code in `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. The function is used in multiple components. It's cleaner to do:

```
connect(
  state => ({
    someFunction: bindStateToSomeFunction(state),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    anotherFunction: bindDispatchToAnotherFunction(dispatch),
  }),
);
```

However, when a function needs both state and dispatch, I don't know how to handle it. It there a way to access both state and dispatch in a Redux `connect` callback?

Comment: you should add `redux-thunk` as a piece of middleware to redux. this will give you the ability to access state and dispatch like you want

Comment: Also, binding state and dispatch in connect this way is a more verbose way to do it. When you connect a component, `dispatch` is exposed as a prop on the component. You can just dispatch from the component itself :)

Comment: `redux-thunk` is a good idea. I already have it installed for async, but didn't realized this is another use-case

Comment: Yep! Sounds like an easy fix then! If you want to share your project I'm happy to help show how to clean up / less verbose code with redux-thunk and stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
function createDispatcherAndSelectorFunctions(...args) {
    return {
         dispatcher: (id, name) => ({
            type: "MY ACTION"
            payload: {
                id, name
            }
         }),              
         selector: (state) => state.foo
    } 
}


const {dispatcher, selector} = createDispatcherAndSelectorFunctions("hello world"); 

connect(
    state => ({
        data: selector(state), 
    }), 
    dispatch => ({
        fn: (id, name) => dispatch(dispatcher(id, name))
    })
);
```